# Regex Finding Name and Surname on the String for ID Card

Tags: c#, regex

I'm reading the ID card with OCR. How can I get the name and surname here?

Example of ID card (see also at: https://regex101.com/r/8EKjFU/1):

```
TÜRKIYE CUMHURIYETI
NÜFUS CÜZDANI
CUMHURYETI TURKIYE CUMHURIYE
H12
SERTTURKIYE CUMHURIYETI 1
11111111111
HKIYE CUMHURIY
URI YETI TURKIYE CUMH
T.C. KIMLIK NO.
SOYAD
DEMIRAL
ADI
SERHAT
BABA ADI
BILAL
```

Fixed Variables: `SOYAD` , `ADI` and `BABA`

Example Output: `SERHAT` `DEMIRAL`

Thanks for helping

Comment: The short answer is _YOU CAN'T_ parse language with regular expressions. Can't get names adjectives, verbs, context, absolutely nothing !!

Comment: The text is in Turkish and what the OP means by name is "ADI" and by surname "SOYAD". The question might have been more descriptive, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [lookbehind assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to capture them.

The following matches DEMIRAL .

```
(?<=^SOYAD\n)(.+)
```

The following matches SERHAT:

```
(?<=^ADI\n)(.+)
```

However, you can use the following to get both:

```
(?<=^SOYAD\n)(.+)\nADI\n(.+)
```

With this, \1 will point to SOYAD and \2 to ADI.

Working sample: https://regex101.com/r/8EKjFU/2

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56827023/6553328), I'm guessing that maybe this expression:

```
(?:SOYAD\s*|ADI\s*|BABA\sADI\s*)(\S+)
```

might return our desire values.

#### Example

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?:SOYAD\s*|ADI\s*|BABA\sADI\s*)(\S+)";
        string input = @"TÜRKIYE CUMHURIYETI
NÜFUS CÜZDANI
CUMHURYETI TURKIYE CUMHURIYE
H12
SERTTURKIYE CUMHURIYETI 1
11111111111
HKIYE CUMHURIY
URI YETI TURKIYE CUMH
T.C. KIMLIK NO.
SOYAD
DEMIRAL
ADI
SERHAT
BABA ADI
BILAL
";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gkBx4X/1), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.